# Python won't recognize mysql.connector even though I have it installed?

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, connector

I installed mysql connector with pip, so now I have:

```
$ pip install mysql-connector
Requirement already satisfied: mysql-connector in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

I also tried:

```
$ pip install mysql-connector-python-rf
Requirement already satisfied: mysql-connector-python-rf in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Now in my test file I just have:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
```

But when I run this I get:

```
$ python mysqlTest.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mysqlTest.py", line 1, in <module>
      import mysql.connector
  File "/home/user/mysql.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named connector
```

I'm running on ubuntu and just to verify, here's my python version:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Include the mysql connector version also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like there is something wrong with your module's path. Maybe you're importing the wrong module. I would try to `print mysql.__file__` to make sure you're importing the right module.

In addition, using `virtualenv` is almost guaranteed to solve this kind of problems which usually stem from collisions between different Python interpreters and / or modules with similar names.

## Using virtualenv

1. Run `pip install virtualenv` to install virtualenv.
2. Run `virtualenv venv` to create a Python virtual environment in your current directory.
3. Run `source venv/bin/activate` to activate the virtual environment.
4. Install your dependencies (mysql) using `pip` as you normally would and try running the script again.

More info on virtualenv can be found in the [official docs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/).

Comment: Thanks a lot Johanan. Using virtualenv fixed the problem immediately.